# unable to permit strong parameters in nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-attributes

I am trying to store the data in multiple tables using single form.

```
  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:status,:display_name, 
    :acc_billing_address_attributes =>[
    :first_name, :last_name])
 end
```

My problem is that when ever I try to store data in tables,data is stored successfully in account table and in acc_billing_addresses table,blank data is stored in table with the error: `Unpermitted parameter:acc_billing_address`
The values are retrieved in params.
In my controller i have:

```
    def create
      @account = Account.new(account_params)
      @account.build_acc_billing_address
    end
```

My model is:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
has_one :acc_billing_address
accepts_nested_attributes_for :acc_billing_address
end
```

and

```
class AccBillingAddress < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :account
end
```

This is my form

```
<%= form_for(:account, url:  account_index_path) do |f| %>

      <table border = "0", cellpadding = "10", cellspacing = "0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <b> Branding Options</b>
            <td align = "left", height = "25"> Display Name</td>
            <td align = "left">
              <%= f.text_field :display_name%>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
          <%= f.fields_for :acc_billing_address do |builder| %>
            <tr>
              <b> Billing Address </b>
              <td align = "left", height = "25"> Contact First Name</td>
              <td align = "left">
                <%= builder.text_field :first_name %>
              </td>
              <td align = "left", height = "25"> parent id</td>
              <td align = "left">                  
              </td>
              <td align = "left", height = "25"> Contact Last Name</td>
              <td align = "left">
                <%= builder.text_field :last_name %>
              </td>
            </tr>

          <% end %>
          <tr>
            <td align = "left">  
              <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: did you give `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?

Comment: Looks like you're not using `fields_for` in your form. Could you please add your form code?

Comment: yes.I am using fields_for in my form

Comment: :acc_billing_address_attributes =>[ :first_name, :last_name])   SHOULD BE 'acc_billing_address: [:first_name,:last_name]' in your params.permit method.

Comment: @nkunzi01, if i change to acc_billing_address:[:first_name,:last_name], I got the error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (AccBillingAddress(#70161417568060) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess